# Difficulties with the handling of files after shutdown or reboot

Tags: c++, windows, fstream, application-shutdown

I wrote a little application which is able to log some data and writes it via ofstream into a file:

```
ofstream filename;              
filename.open("filename.ext", ios::out | ios::app);
filename << stuff;
```

This file is closed and re-opened every 30sec.
A second file "settings.ext" is used to define the programms behavior. The function looks like following:

```
ifstream input("settings.qib", ios::in);
    string number;
    for (string line; getline(input, line); )
    {
        if (line.find("updateInterval") != string::npos) {
            number = "";
            for (int i = 0; !isspace(line.at(i)); i++) number += line.at(i);
            updateInterval = stoi(number);
        }
        if (line.find("visibility") != string::npos) {
            number = "";
            for (int i = 0; !isspace(line.at(i)); i++) number += line.at(i);
            Stealth(stoi(number));
        }
        if (line.find("console") != string::npos) {
            number = "";
            for (int i = 0; !isspace(line.at(i)); i++) number += line.at(i);
            console = stoi(number);
        }
    }
```

This was the best i could come up with to read out a file like so:

> 0 = visibility
>
> 1 = console
>
> 30 = updateInterval

Everything works great. The settings are refreshed in the same rythm as the log file is flushed.

I created a Registry Entry for the entire to program to startup at every start, which works fine aswell.
But after a shutdown or reboot the program seems to ignore the two files. No new content is added to the log file and the settings arent refreshd either.

I am guessing this has something to do with the fact, that log file is open during the shutdown, but this doesnt explain why the setting file isnt touched either.

I have read some things about the `WM_ENDSESSION` but I'm not sure if that is the right way to go.

I'm open for all kinds of answers, or other ways to achieve my goal.

Comment: Put `::DebugBreak();` at the start of your program this will allow you to attach a debugger when the auto-starts.

Comment: Are you sure your program runs at all after a reboot?

Comment: It runs very well, even the logging functions are working properly. But the program isn't able to open the files.

Answer (score 0):

After many reboots i figured, that current working directory is stated as /system32 after the startup. No wonder the files could be opened.
First: In system32 are no such files located.
Second: The program doesnt have permission to write in that directory.
To solve this, I changend the directory using _chdir() and everythink works like a charm.